# Mysql and php- drag and drop image to upload in database

Tags: php, mysql, image, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to do a drag and drop image with php to upload pictures to database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a front end library (Javascript) to catch the event of dropping the object into the page, and then submitting it via an Ajax request - yes it is possible. The other (uglier) route is to have a Java applet that does it (still through ajax).

I wouldnt store the images in the database though. Store them in a filesystem with the path specifics stored in the DB.

Comment: OK. do you have an example of the AJAX or Applet code.. So i can follow as reference

Comment: Thanks I will be going through it.

Comment: Accept this answer if it works for you by clicking the Checkmark!